# 10 NICs in 1U box - possible?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, hardware, tcp, nic

I am looking for a device with 10 NICs in one 1U box. The CPU can be anything even a microcontroller as long as it can process TCP packets. I would prefer a sort of Linux on it but is open to other suggestions. It has to be an industrial grade hardware though. Not bunch of raspberry pies bundled together with an electrical tape.

I want to be able to send 10 HTTP requests at same time to different URLs and then communicate its availability to a central server ran on a regular hardware via TCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy one for a change! there's loads of 4-port PCIe NICs available - literally google '4 port NIC'. I'm not aware of there being >4-port ones but obviously two of them plus any built-in LOM/mLOMs will give you enough.

Any modern OS will support this without a problem - though you might wish to rename the ports once they're up so you know which is which :)

Oh and finally why not just have multiple virtual NICs off one port, either via VLAN tagging or just as separate MACs/IPs?

Comment: thank you. `multiple virtual NICs off one port` - i never heard of it. my knowledge of networking is a bit outdated :) i am gonna need to learn new tricks